# What are the best practices when it comes to using static memory allocation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm brand new to Objective-C.

Right now, I'm about to C-based calls (open()) and I'm wondering... is it OK of me to use just a plan ol' statically allocated int?

I understand Objective-C is all about the dynamic memory allocation so... what are the general best practices when it comes down to using static memory allocation in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For primitive types, stick with your standard methods of declaring them. No pointers needed. Objective-C is only all about the dynamic memory allocation when it comes to Objective-C classes. With those, you have no choice. The compiler will actually throw an error if you try to allocate an Obj-C object on the stack.

Basically your frame of mind should be to never use C-style anything unless absolutely necessary, mandated either by your app's requirements or by the framework you are using (for example, the `CoreFoundation` framework is all C-based). But even in the case of something like `CoreFoundation`, you'll almost never have to call things like `open()` or `malloc()` directly; the framework has all that wrapped up nicely in higher-level functions so you don't have to get too down and dirty.